# Magento 1.7 - add attribute to order_item and setting value

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to add a new attribute to `order_item`

install-0.1.0.php

```
$installer->addAttribute('order_item', 'xxx', array('type'=>'text', 'visible' => true, 'required' => false, 'is_user_defined' => true, 'note' => 'Field comment'));  
$installer->addAttribute('quote_item', 'xxx', array('type'=>'text', 'visible' => true, 'required' => false, 'is_user_defined' => true, 'note' => 'Field comment'));
```

I see 2 new rows in `eav_attribute`

[image: screenshot]

Running this two times prints nothing:

```
    $item = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item');
    $item->load(91);

    $item->setXxx("test");
    $item->setData("xxx", "test");

    print $item->getXxx();

    $item->save();
```

How do I set and get a value in an order item for this attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `sales/order` and `sales/order_item` does not inherit or use the eav_attribute structure in Magento. This blog post explains it pretty well: http://www.krilion.net/blog/2012/08/adding-a-custom-attribute-to-a-magento-order/

The jist of it is that you'll need to create your installer script to create a new column in the flat table (`sales_flat_order_item`) in order to save your new value. You should be able to save your xxx value as soon as there's an xxx column in the flat table. This means your installer script needs to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup` and not `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`.